# Задать функцию для элемента без Id и др. атрибутов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Заранее прошу извинения за возможно глупый вопрос, но сам не могу справиться, т.к. плохо владею JS.

Сайт сделан на конструкторе ***Platforma LP***, т.е. влезть в код я не могу.

Есть такое поле для ввода номера в контактной форме:

```js
$("#telephone").intlTelInput({
  allowDropdown: true,
  autoPlaceholder: "agressive",
  initialCountry: "de"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field" data-type="phone">
  <div class="name">Telefonnummer</div>
  <div class="input">
    <input class="form-control text" style="border-radius: 4px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно в форму вставить выпадающий список телефонных кодов стран. Для этого пользуюсь скриптом с кодом:

Вопрос в следующем:

У `input` нет `id`, `value` и других уникальных атрибутов. Что прописать в переменную, чтобы скрипт работал только в этом поле?

Если копировать селектор из отладчика, то получается слишком массивно:

> body>div.area.font-text-opensans.font-header-opensans.screen-lg>div.modal.fade.nocolors.in>div>div>div.modal-body>div>div>div>div>div>form>div.fields>div:nth-child(2)>div.input>input

Можно ли как-то средствами JS задать id этому input, а потом использовать его в скрипте?

Comment: например: `[data-type="phone"] .input .form-control`

Comment: к сожалению, этот вариант не сработал: <script>
        $("[data-type="phone"] .input .form-control").intlTelInput({
             allowDropdown: true,
            autoPlaceholder: "agressive",
            initialCountry: "de",
});
    </script>

Comment: потому что ты записал неправильно. Ты внутри строки заданной двойными кавычками используешь двойные кавычки. их надо либо экранировать, либо заменить на одинарные

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо, работает! Напишите это сообщение не комментарием, а ответом. Я отмечу как лучший.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разумеется можно.

У инпута есть класс, как и у его родителя. Конкретно к инпуту доступ можете получить так

```js
let input = document.querySelector('div.input > .form-control.text');
```

Если с помощью jQuery

```js
let input = $('div.input > .form-control.text');
```

Если хотите вставлять какие-то атрибуты, например id

```js
let input = $('div.input > .form-control.text');
input.id = 'myInput';
```